# Must declare Scalar variable - error from parameter

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a dataset query as below:

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM Table
WHERE @DatabaseGrowth = 'DatabaseGrowthByLast7Days'

UNION ALL

SELECT col3, col4
FROM Table
WHERE @DatabaseGrowth = 'DatabaseGrowthByLast4Weeks'
```

and have a parameter named `DatabaseGrowth`. While running the report, if I select `DatabaseGrowthByLast7Days`, it should return `7Days`. But, it is showing error

> Must declare Scalar variable "@DatabaseGrowth"

What is wrong with my dataset code?
The above code is sample code of my actual code.

Edited the code above.

Comment: Show how you have declared ?. SQL parameter it should be declared like this `Declare @DatabaseGrowth varchar(500)`

Comment: It was not required to declare while I used different parameter in different place. `Select.....From table ...Where ColumnName in (@param)`. it is working without declaring.

Comment: when you use `@variablename` in `SQL SERVER` it should be declared before it is used

Comment: As this is a SQL Server Reporting Services question, the answers telling you to declare the variables are missing the point; SSRS configures the parameters, if you configure your SSRS Report correctly.  Is this what you're trying to do; https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337400(v=sql.105).aspx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below way, If you are using it in SSRS dataset, no need to declare it. If you delete your existing parameter and add the below code to dataset. It will automatically create a parameter with name `DatabaseGrowth`.

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM Table
WHERE 'DatabaseGrowthByLast7Days' = (@DatabaseGrowth)

UNION ALL

SELECT col3, col4
FROM Table
WHERE 'DatabaseGrowthByLast4Weeks' = (@DatabaseGrowth)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @DatabaseGrowth varchar(500)= 'DatabaseGrowthByLast4Weeks'
SELECT '7Days' as val
WHERE @DatabaseGrowth = 'DatabaseGrowthByLast7Days'

UNION ALL

SELECT '4Weeks' as val
WHERE @DatabaseGrowth = 'DatabaseGrowthByLast4Weeks'
```

Comment: After adding `declare @DatabaseGrowth nvarchar(max)= 'DatabaseGrowthByLast7Days'`, it gives me result as `7Days` even after selecting `DatabaseGrowthByLast4Weeks`.

Comment: i eddited my answer can u check once  @pkawar

Answer (score 0):

At first you need to declare a variable `@DatabaseGrowth`. Then you can use [CASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) expression:

> Evaluates a list of conditions and returns one of multiple possible result expressions.

```
DECLARE @DatabaseGrowth nvarchar(max) = 'DatabaseGrowthByLast7Days'

SELECT CASE WHEN @DatabaseGrowth = 'DatabaseGrowthByLast4Weeks' THEN '4Weeks' 
            WHEN @DatabaseGrowth = 'DatabaseGrowthByLast7Days' THEN '7Days'  
            ELSE NULL END as val
```

Or:

```
SELECT CASE @DatabaseGrowth  
            WHEN 'DatabaseGrowthByLast4Weeks' THEN '4Weeks' 
            WHEN 'DatabaseGrowthByLast7Days' THEN '7Days'  
            ELSE NULL END as val
```

**EDIT**

Based on your edit:

```
DECLARE @DatabaseGrowth nvarchar(max) = 'DatabaseGrowthByLast4Weeks'

SELECT  [Col1], 
        [Col2]
FROM [Table]
WHERE @DatabaseGrowth = 'DatabaseGrowthByLast7Days'
UNION ALL
SELECT  [Col3], 
        [Col4]
FROM [Table]
WHERE @DatabaseGrowth = 'DatabaseGrowthByLast4Weeks'
```

Be aware that `[Col1]` should be the same data type as `[Col3]` and `[Col2]` same as `[Col4]`.

Comment: I have a long select list and the data will be filtered based on parameter selected (like if I select `DatabaseGrowthByLast7Days`, the second part after UNION ALL will be ignored). Therefore, I need the check in WHERE clause.

Comment: And? You can use `WHERE some_column = CASE... etc`